# Is there a way to have ManyToMany relationship in Laravel without creating a third table connecting both entities manually?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I am implementing a Laravel REST API backend and I have two tables, trip_announcements (user announcing their trip) and countries (self explanatory). Each announcement can have multiple countries.

I ended up creating two functions:

```
    //Models\TripAnnouncement
    public function countries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class);
    }
```

and

```
    //Models\Country
    public function trips(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(TripAnnouncement::class);
    }
```

Then I created a new migration file:

```
class CreateTripCountriesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('country_trip_announcement', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('trip_announcement_id')->constrained('trip_announcements')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('country_id')->constrained('countries')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('country_trip_announcement');
    }
}
```

It does work as intended but I am a bit confused whether it's a right way to do that. I expected the ORM to kind of link the two tables for me instead of having to create the linking table myself. Is my solution ok or is there a simpler way to do that in Laravel 8?

Comment: Seems like it would be a simple task to [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to know if you're doing something correctly...

Comment: the [`calebporzio/sushi`](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) package offers a way to declare models (and their data) manually. However, it is very, very limited and ultimately, should only be used for static data like Cities and such. `hasMany`  and `belongsTo` relationship work well enough but anything other than that (`belongsToMany`) won't work

Answer (score 2):

Many to many relationships require an intermediate table to link your two models together.

In Laravel, the Eloquent ORM is separate from database migrations. You need to create both the intermediate table as a migration, and link the two models via relationships.

The way you've coded your relationship is the correct way of doing it. Have a read of [the docs here.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)